# Split multicast traffic on two vlans using IOS

Tags: ios, multicast

Here is what I want to do:

On a switch / router running cisco IOS ( Ideally it would work  on a Lanbase image on a 3560G but it is possible to use 65xx routers also ) I receive two udp multicast streams on vlan 100:

- vlan 100, @239.34.1.1:1234 and @239.34.1.2:1234

What I need to do is to forward:

- @239.34.1.1:1234 on vlan 101
- @239.34.1.2:1234 on vlan 102

For the time being I do not care about igmp snooping, which is disabled (  multicast traffic is treated as broadcast ), but an ideal solution would forward igmp queries from vlan 101/102 to vlan 100.

As suggested by @metacom I did the following:

I am running: ipbasek9 /  12.2(44)SE6

```
ip multicast-routing distributed
no ip igmp snooping
ip igmp ssm-map enable
no ip igmp ssm-map query dns
ip igmp ssm-map static 11 192.168.0.41
ip igmp ssm-map static 12 192.168.0.1
ip igmp ssm-map static 16 192.168.0.6
vlan 100
 name video feeds a and b
vlan 101
 name video a

interface vlan 100
 ip address 192.168.0.146 255.255.255.0
 # How am I supposed to explain that feeds 239.34.1.1 and 239.34.1.2 have a source on vlan 100?
 ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.2 source ssm-map
 ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.1 source ssm-map
 ip pim passive

interface vlan 101
 ip address 172.16.5.17 255.255.255.248
 ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.1 source ssm-map
 ip pim passive

ip pim ssm range 88

access-list 11 permit 239.34.1.1
access-list 12 permit 239.34.1.2

access-list 88 permit 239.34.1.1
access-list 88 permit 239.34.1.2
```

With this configuration, I have a server with a trunk connection to both vlans.
On vlan 100 I can see ( via tcpdump for example ) the 239.34.1.1 and 239.34.1.2 streams.
On vlan 101 I do not have any multicast streams.

When I run `show ip mroute` I see nothing.
I do not know how to configure pim. In this image I have only `pim passive` , I do not know if it is a good or bad thing to  activate it.

*EDIT*

I have activated `ip pim passive` on both SVI 
and here is the result for `show ip igmp groups 239.34.1.1`

```
Group Address    Interface                Uptime    Expires   Last
Reporter   Group Accounted
239.34.1.1       Vlan101                 00:07:19  stopped   0.0.0.0         
239.34.1.1       Vlan100                 00:07:31  stopped   192.168.0.36
```

Also if I run `show ip mroute 239.34.1.1` I do not have an incoming interface for this group:

```
#show ip mroute 239.34.1.1
IP Multicast Routing Table
Flags: D - Dense, S - Sparse, B - Bidir Group, s - SSM Group, C - Connected,
       L - Local, P - Pruned, R - RP-bit set, F - Register flag,
       T - SPT-bit set, J - Join SPT, M - MSDP created entry,
       X - Proxy Join Timer Running, A - Candidate for MSDP Advertisement,
       U - URD, I - Received Source Specific Host Report, 
       Z - Multicast Tunnel, z - MDT-data group sender, 
       Y - Joined MDT-data group, y - Sending to MDT-data group
       V - RD & Vector, v - Vector
Outgoing interface flags: H - Hardware switched, A - Assert winner
 Timers: Uptime/Expires
 Interface state: Interface, Next-Hop or VCD, State/Mode

(192.168.0.1, 239.34.1.1), 00:14:42/00:02:34, flags: sTI
  Incoming interface: Null, RPF nbr 0.0.0.0
  Outgoing interface list:
    Vlan101, Forward/Sparse-Dense, 00:14:29/00:00:44
    Vlan100, Forward/Sparse-Dense, 00:14:41/00:02:34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, I think that it is simply impossible to route multicast traffic with a lanbase image.

As stated in the doc [If you need PIM for an SVI uplink port, you should upgrade to the IP services feature set.](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/12-2_53_se/configuration/guide/3750xscg/swmcast.html)

On a old 3550 running 12.1(22)EA1a, the trivial following configuration is working fine:

```
ip multicast-routing

interface Vlan100
 ip address 192.168.0.146 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
end

interface Vlan101
 ip address 172.16.5.17 255.255.255.248
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.1 source 192.168.0.1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Static Traffic Forwarding with SSM Mapping :
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipmulti_igmp/configuration/xe-3s/imc-igmp-xe-3s-book/imc_ssm_map.html#GUID-DDD77D1A-D5C2-4402-A7C6-D1728B94A833

This sounds like exactly what you need.

The configuration would add an acl for vlan101 permitting 239.34.1.1 and one for vlan 102 allowing 239.34.1.2. Enable pim sparse-mode on all 3 vlans, ssm-map, multicast-routign and you should be good to go!

**Edit:**  I just closed 44 tabs from trying to figure this out!

**Edit 2:** Change

```
ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.2 source 192.168.0.1
ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.1 source 192.168.0.41
```

to

```
 ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.2 source ssm-map
 ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.1 source ssm-map
```

**Edit** 3
From here: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipmulti/command/imc-cr-book/imc_i2.html#wp1533460393

```
ip mroute 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.146
```

And also you can probably remove

```
 ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.2 source ssm-map
 ip igmp static-group 239.34.1.1 source ssm-map
```

from vlan 100

Comment: I tried ssm but I can't get it work. Can you look my configuration and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: could you give me the output of: show ip igmp group 239.34.1.1 detail and also enable passive pim on both vlans

Comment: I have edited the question with the requested configuration changes / request

Comment: Check Edit 2.. the formatting in the answer section makes it easier!

Comment: I did the change, the question is edited. No change on the show ip mroute and show ip igmp groups results. And still no multicast traffic flooded on vlan 101

Comment: And if edit 3 doesnt work, I give up! Also, can you show the output of  show ip rpf 192.168.0.1

Comment: I have error: %Invalid RPF neighbor address (it's this router)